# Express: express.json() or express.urlencoded() does not work

Tags: json, node.js, express

If I write post request like this:

```
app.post('/sendCoins', [express.urlencoded(), express.json()], function(req, res) {
    //console.log(req.body.toAddress);
    console.log(req.body.amount);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    res.send('hi');
});
```

console prints `undefined`.
But when I use `express.bodyParser()` application starts with connect.multipart() wanring but prints the request properly.

```
"123"
{"amount":"123","toAddress":"99999999"}
```

As per express documentation I should not use `express.bodyParser()`

Comment: What's the `Content-Type` of the request? Each of the 3 body parsers only works with a specific type.

Comment: Jonathan may be on to something: if your form encoding is `multipart/form-data`, `.bodyParser()` would work because it includes the (soon to be removed) `.multipart()`.  I would check that first.  If you need to parse multipart content, look at Busboy or Formidable.

Comment: As per documentation, req.body is an object containing the parsed request body. This feature is provided by the bodyParser(). So if you don't use this, req.body will be undefined

Comment: As @JonathanLonowski say you should provide content type of your request, for example `express.json()` can handle only forms which have `<form enctype="JSON">` or `<form> enctype="application/json">`.